# Marmalade ErrorCode 4 while building mkb project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sdk, marmalade

I've got a project from my teacher, that I should run in the Marmalade Hub. I've imported this project en tried to run it. At first I got an error with the error code 7.

```
error: Visual Studio 2013 Express Windows Desktop requested but not found instal
led.
FAILED (error code=7)
```

I've fixed this problem to change the C++ Development (IDE's and Compilers) from  'Visual studio Express 2013 Windows Desktop' to 'Visual Studio 2013' (see image below). I did this change, because I do have 'Visual Studio Proffesional 2013 for Windows Desktop' and not 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop'. 'Visual Studio 2013 Proffesional 2013 for Windows Desktop' doesn't exist in the drop down. [image: IDE's and Compilers]

I tried again to run the project (see image below) and I did get another error with the error code 4:

```
-- Visual Studio Output --
1>------ Build started: Project: minimal_marmalade_vc12, Configuration: x86 Debu
g Win32 ------
1>LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/FORCE' specification
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'cgl_d.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

-- End Visual Studio Output --
error: build failed: '['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\C
ommon7\\IDE\\devenv.exe', 'minimal_marmalade_vc12.sln', '/build', 'X86 Debug', '
/out', 'vs_output_11728.log']' (1)
FAILED (error code=4)
```

[image: Interface]

I hope you guys (or girls ;) ) can solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that your project uses the library Core Media Library. Check whether used somewhere in the code header file cgl.h If so, then reinstall [Core Media Library](http://www.coremedialibrary.com/?page=119) Instalation instructions you find in this [guide](http://www.coremedialibrary.com/downloads/tutorials/installation_visualstudio.pdf)